Upload 1 file at a time using FilePond
Currently the Filepond property:  allowMultiple:true is necessary to allow users to upload several files but it is extremely dangerous as it does not respect the input file type's multiple property.
This means a user can upload 1000 images in one click which could be disasterous.
Is there any way of getting round this?
